# How can navigation be aborted even if goal is not reached?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

how can I cancel navigation with move_base and stop the robot by sending a message or a service call even if the goal sent to move_base is not reached yet?

Regards,
Sabrina

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11864/how-can-navigation-be-aborted-even-if-goal-is-not-reached?/) by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2011-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Or from the command line,

```
$ rostopic pub move_base/cancel actionlib_msgs/GoalID '{}'
```

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2011-11-09**:
Thank you, that was the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The navigation stack operates using actionlib. Thus, to communicate with move_base, you must use actionlib's ActionClient to send commands and receive feedback. For simplicity, you can use the following code:

```
typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> NavClient;

class MyClass
{
  private:
      NavClient nav_client_;
  ...
}

MyClass::MyClass() : nav_client_("move_base", true) 
{
  ...
}

MyClass::cancelNavigation()
{
  nav_client_.cancelAllGoals();
}
```

For more advanced actionlib usage, you can find complete documentation on actionlib [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2011-11-09**:
Thank you for your answer. This solution seems reasonable, but I'm looking for a more convenient way where no coding is needed. That's why I voted for bhaskara's answer.